# Is there a character that Java serialization doesn't use?

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize objects to be sent through a socket from server to client, and the network package I am using only allows Strings to be sent. I would like to be able to send command codes with the object so the client knows what to do with the object when it gets it. The problem is that every time I choose a character to split the String message on, I wind up sooner or later with a serialized object that contains that character. I've tried "+", "*", "&", "@" and several other characters and they seem to work for a while, but eventually they wind up being used in the objects.

The only thing that has worked for me so far is using a character sequence like "|*|*|*|*|*|*|" in the hopes that this will be a one in a billion fluke if it winds up in a serialized object, but with my luck it probably will.

Any ideas?

Comment: Serialisation is **not a `String`**. It is random bytes! You need to encode to Base64 and that will also help with the split. You **cannot** send random bytes as strings. You will eventually end up corrupting the stream by coercing then bytes into a string.

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve but how about converting your object to Json and sending it as string? This way it will be wrapped in `{..}` or `[ ]` if it is array.